# Image Slider buttons not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a image slider where you can browse them through the prev and next buttons. Actually it's a pretty simple slider, but I'm just starting at jQuery. Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $active = $('.active');
    var $next = $active.next();
    var $prev = $active.prev();

    $('.next').click(function () {
        $next.addClass('active');
        $active.removeClass('active');
    })

    $('.prev').click(function () {
        $prev.addClass('active');
        $active.removeClass('active');
    })
});
```

//Edit

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="imgslider">
        <img src="" class="active"/>
        <img src=""/>
        <img src=""/>
        <div class="slidercontrols">
            <div class="prev">&lsaquo;</div>
            <div class="next">&rsaquo;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .active{
    z-index: 4;
}

    .prev, .next
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 55px;
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    margin-top: -25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: .7;
    transition: all 150ms;
}
```

The script doesnt work. I mean, when I click either of the buttons they don't do anything, and I don't know if the problem is the script or the html-css file.

Comment: What do you want them to do? You're just adding / removing classes to it.

Comment: can you please post you slider content.. i mean the image and arrow image code you have in you html page?? then only we can check..

Answer (score 1):

You have to use common class name for all the images inside the slider.. Before adding class `active` you have to remove all the `active` class in that slider. Then you have to add active class for present slider.

**HTML :**

```
<img src="image/1.jpg" class="imageClass" />
<img src="image/2.jpg" class="imageClass active" />
<img src="image/3.jpg" class="imageClass" />
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $active = $('.active');
    var $next = $active.next();
    var $prev = $active.prev();

    $('.next').click(function() {
        //imageClass represents class name used for all images
        $('.imageClass').removeClass('active'); 
        $next.addClass('active');
    });

    $('.prev').click(function() {
        //imageClass represents class name used for all images
        $('.imageClass').removeClass('active');
        $prev.addClass('active');
    });
});
```